# Open link in Facebook app if available

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, url

I want to open a page in the Facebook app if the user has it installed on his device.
Now, I am using the following code I found while doing research:

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "fb://profile/myPage'sID")!
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(myUrl) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(myUrl)
} else {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/myPage")!)
}
```

This does work for a **profile** but does not for displaying a **page**.
(Note that both IDs do work, as I tested them.)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've done that before for a Facebook page. Try using another page id to test.  fb://profile/197394889304 (Barcelona FC Facebook page)

Comment: Nope, opens the site in Safari as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think then it may be caused because you need to add this key-value to the Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) (Weirdly it worked a couple weeks ago, maybe b/c of iOS 8.4...)